# wpa_supplicant reply to any command with UNKNOWN COMMAND except PING, LIST_NETWORKS, ATTACH, DETACH, TERMINATE, and STATUS?

Tags: android, c++, wpa-supplicant

First of all my target system is android.
I created a c++ application to communicate with wpa_supplicant through the control interface provided as a wpa_ctrl.c file (I included the header file wpa_ctrl.h and linked with the library libwpa_client.so) 
[here is the documentation page](https://w1.fi/wpa_supplicant/devel/ctrl_iface_page.html).
Every thing was working fine, but suddenly every command I send is replied by UNKNOWN COMMAND, I suppose that the commands that work fine (ping, list_networks, status, and terminate) have a common thing (maybe they do not need to open the wpa_supplicant.conf which causes the problem on other commands)

here is how I open the connection:

```
this->ctrl = wpa_ctrl_open(this->socket.c_str());
```

here is how I send commands:

```
s = wpa_ctrl_request(this->ctrl, cmd.c_str(), cmd.length(), this->_reply, &reply_len, msg_cb);
```

above method signatures:

```
struct wpa_ctrl * wpa_ctrl_open(const char *ctrl_path);

int wpa_ctrl_request(struct wpa_ctrl *ctrl, const char *cmd, size_t cmd_len,
         char *reply, size_t *reply_len,
         void (*msg_cb)(char *msg, size_t len));
```

example output:

```
PING
PONG

UNKNOWN COMMAND: MIB
UNKNOWN COMMAND: STATUS-VERBOSE
UNKNOWN COMMAND: PMKSA
UNKNOWN COMMAND: LOGON
UNKNOWN COMMAND: LOGOFF
UNKNOWN COMMAND: REASSOCIATE
UNKNOWN COMMAND: RECONNECT
UNKNOWN COMMAND: RECONFIGURE
LIST_NETWORKS
network id / ssid / bssid / flags

UNKNOWN COMMAND: DISCONNECT
UNKNOWN COMMAND: SCAN
UNKNOWN COMMAND: SCAN_RESULTS
UNKNOWN COMMAND: BSS
UNKNOWN COMMAND: ADD_NETWORK
STATUS
p2p_device_address=12:d3:8a:c8:34:ef
p2p_state=IDLE
wifi_display=1
ifname=p2p0
address=12:d3:8a:c8:34:ef
ifname=wlan0
address=10:d3:8a:c8:34:ef

UNKNOWN COMMAND: ADD_NETWORK
closed connection with wpa_supplicant.
Can not create Network
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fj6c3.png) is a screenshot of an older version of the program working almost fine:

any help is appreciated.

EDIT: I tested the program on my other device and it worked well. But still broken on my main device, probably a factory reset will solve it. But I still want to know the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the interface name was wrong.

Comment: Thank you. The problem is actually that wpa_cli UI returns confusing and unhelpful error messages. This is a serious flaw. Thanks for the tip about the interface name.